# Como crear un marcador personalizado con dos iconos en gmap v3

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

necesito poder tener un marcador con por lo menos dos iconos distintos, uno de los cuales tiene que llevar un numero indicador float dentro de el, se me ocurre crear dos marcadores en la misma posición pero uno con un icono en .png con un margen, claramente esta opción no es la mas optima y tendría aun la duda de como ingresar el valor numérico, alguna idea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Puedes cargar el icono del marcador en un canvas, modificarlo y después exportarlo como una URL para crear tu icono

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var img = new Image();
var markerUrl;
var marker;
img.addEventListener("load", function() {
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        ctx.fillText('1.5', 50, 50); // Esto añade el texto '1.5' en la
                                     // posición x: 50, y: 50 de la imagen.
    }
    markerUrl = canvas.toDataURL();  // Exportamos el canvas modificado como
                                     // una URL

    // Creamos el marker con la URL que acabamos de obtener
    marker = new google.maps.MarkerImage(markerUrl, 
                 new google.maps.Size(size.width, size.height));
}, false);

// En esta imagen cargamos la imagen original, esto hará que se dispare el
// evento load de
img.src='marker.png';
```

Comment: excelente funciono impecable!!! ahora a ingresarlo en la ensalada de codigo! un saludo